# I need help approching this problem: Generating a table with dynamic columns, export in .xlsx from Apex, transposing rows to columns

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I'm writing here because I don't really know how to approach this. I'm searching for a hint.
The db is Oracle 18c and i'm working in Apex 21.2. I'm developing a small application to ingest data via excel files and save it in some tables.
The data is some products information and attributes, like "Product SKU 12345678 have color yellow, the material is ABS and the diameter is 2".

I have 5 tables: One for the products(ID, SKU, PRICE, qty) then the product attributes are stored in 3 tables:

1. T_ATTRIBUTES: the name of the attributes, like ID=1 VALUE=DIAMETER, ID=2 VALUE=COLOR, ID=3 VALUE=MATERIAL
2. T_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES: the values for each attribute, like "DIAMETER HAVE VALUES 1,2,3,4". Each values is a different entry. the T_ATTRIBUES.ID is a FK
3. T_PRODUCT_VALUES: it contains the relationship between a product and the value. T_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES.ID is the FK relation. So a i have each row for the couple product, values. For example "Product ID 12346 have values ID 12, ID 23, ID 43. There is not direct relationship with attributes but it is derived from t_attributes_values.

Now, the problem: The import file that we use to populate this table have one attribute for each column and in one row we define each attribute for one sku. The schema is like this:

| PRODUCT_SKU | COLOR | DIAMETER | MATERIAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000000001 | GREEN | 2" | ABS |
| 00000000002 | YELLOW | 1" | PVC |
| 00000000003 | BLUE | 3" | PVDF |

And so on.

The problem is generating back the xlsx file from the tabular data.
If i join all the tables i get one row for each attribute:
ROW_ID: SKU, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_VALUES

| ROW_ID | SKU | ATTR_NAME | ATTR_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 00001 | MATERIAL | ABS |
| 000002 | 00001 | DIAMETER | 2" |
| 000003 | 00001 | COLOR | GREEN |

I've tried with some dynamic SQL but we have abount 360 attributes and the clause will grows outside the maximum 4000 bytes allocation. I've tried to pivot using max (the values field is varchar2) for one row and it's working but attributes could increase or decrease if someone add new attribute to the table so hardcoding values are not an option.

How can I approach this? The aim so I to get an excel out apex with the same format as the input one. I'm not so an export, just started SQL and PLSQL in general about 6 months ago.

Thanks
EDIT: What I was thinking was that by I don't know how to translate my thoughts: having the number of product fixed for each query, I could execute something like this:

select SKU, VALUE as "ATTR_NAME" from  for each one of the attributes and then merge the data. The problem is that i need to merge (JOIN) each column of values (like I said the join operator do).

Answer (score 0):

First I created a table for product values:

```
create table T_PRODUCT_VALUES
(id    number,
 sku   number,
 attribute_name  varchar2(20),
 attribute_value varchar2(200)
);
```

Second insert some data

```
insert into T_PRODUCT_VALUES values (1,1,'MATERIAL','ABD');
insert into T_PRODUCT_VALUES values (4,1,'DIAMETER','2"');
insert into T_PRODUCT_VALUES values (7,1,'COLOR','GREEN');

insert into T_PRODUCT_VALUES values (8,2,'MATERIAL','PVC');
insert into T_PRODUCT_VALUES values (2,2,'DIAMETER','1"');
insert into T_PRODUCT_VALUES values (5,2,'COLOR','YELLOW');

insert into T_PRODUCT_VALUES values (6,3,'MATERIAL','PVDF');
insert into T_PRODUCT_VALUES values (9,3,'DIAMETER','3"');
insert into T_PRODUCT_VALUES values (3,3,'COLOR','BLUE');
```

Query the table:

```
select a.*
from T_PRODUCT_VALUES a;
```

result:

```
ID SKU ATTRIBUTE_NAME ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
 1   1 MATERIAL       ABD            
 2   2 DIAMETER       1"             
 3   3 COLOR          BLUE           
 4   1 DIAMETER       2"             
 5   2 COLOR          YELLOW         
 6   3 MATERIAL       PVDF           
 7   1 COLOR          GREEN          
 8   2 MATERIAL       PVC            
 9   3 DIAMETER       3"
```

Query to get a row for every SKU:

```
select a.sku,
       max(decode(a.attribute_name,'MATERIAL',attribute_value)) as MATERIAL,
       max(decode(a.attribute_name,'DIAMETER',attribute_value)) as DIAMETER,
       max(decode(a.attribute_name,'COLOR',attribute_value))    as COLOR
from T_PRODUCT_VALUES a
group by a.sku;
```

Result

```
SKU MATERIAL DIAMETER COLOR 
  1 ABD      2"       GREEN 
  2 PVC      1"       YELLOW
  3 PVDF     3"       BLUE
```